# Downloads Stops At 2GB For Some Users

Tags: php, nginx, x-sendfile

I have a website that offer downloads of some large files, up to 10gb.

There is an issue with the downloads that doesn't happen to me, and actually doesn't happen to most of my users, but I keep getting messages from some users that their downloads stop at 2gb, and the file is larger that that.

I serve the downloads using [nginx XSendfile](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/) with php:

```
header('X-Accel-Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . $this->getFileSize() );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('X-Accel-Buffering: yes');
header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . $this->getServeDownloadLocation());
```

Running on CentOS 6.6, php 5.5.22, nginx 1.6.2.

Notice: the users don't use old browsers, they use modern browsers like Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you post your php.ini file?

Comment: Perhaps they're downloading to FAT filesystems.

Comment: @Lori I have spoken to one of them, he told me he is downloading to NTFS file system, and also mentioned that the problem happens to him only sometimes, and not always.

Comment: Check your nginx log, is `$body_bytes_sent` always at 2Gb? Also check the `$request_time` to see whether there are any trends.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is not on your side. Some users router have a bug like mine:

https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/271694

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? If this link dies, this answer won't help anyone in future.